# language switcher opens only the home page

Tags: joomla-3.x, helix3

when i switch the language of my site it takes me back to the home page and switches the language even if I'm in another page. I want it to stay on the same page that am opining and switch its language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are in a inner page you have to be sure that that menu item has an association in the other language.
Otherwise you'll go to home page.

Comment: you are welcome